# Google Cloud Endpoint - cast return model

Tags: java, casting, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm a little confused about the returned object from my GoogleCloudEndpoint.

My Android App uses an Object e.g `TestObject` with something like this path: `com.example.classes.TestObject`. My GoogleCloudEndpoint uses this class too and returns it in some methods, but returned objects of those methods are always another generated class like this: `com.example.testApi.model.TestObject.

Now in my App this is very confusing because I have to handle two nearly identical objects with the same name. The only difference between the object types is, that the generated object has private fields with getters & setters, while the original one had public fields. Obviously there is not way to cast those object to the other.

Is there any way to transform this generated object back to the original one? Or should I only use the generated one in my App?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own helpers to transform back and forth. The `model` classes are subclasses of a generic JSON container object.